# Specifying ARN for a ElastiCache Cluster in Multiple region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elasticache

In my cloudformation template I am creating a policy for ElastiCache cluster which is set to have availability in Multiple region, how should I specify the ARN for the ElasticCache cluster.

From the AWS docs

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-elasticache

I'm skipping the cluster-region name below, is this is the way to do this.

```
"ElastiCachePolicy" :{

      "Type" : "AWS::IAM::Policy",
      "Properties" : {
          "PolicyName" : "ElastiCache",
          "PolicyDocument" : {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
            "Action": "elasticache:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:elasticache::account-id:cluster:cluster-name"
            }]
          },
            "Roles": [ { "Ref": "SomeRole" }]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it I got confused between specifying the region with availability zones. I had to specify the region-id regardless of the cluster availability zones.